# Ruby-on-rails web application could not be started because of 'uglifier'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'.

```
Gem Load Error is: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
Backtrace for gem load error is:

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/conversion.rb:23:in `include'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/conversion.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/conversion.rb:22:in `class_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/conversion.rb:22:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/conversion.rb:21:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/conversion.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8.rb:22:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:108:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:108:in `available?'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:63:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:63:in `find'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:63:in `best_available'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:57:in `autodetect'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
/var/www/geia.junyuzhu.com/public_html/testapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/geia.junyuzhu.com/public_html/testapp/config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
/var/www/geia.junyuzhu.com/public_html/testapp/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
 (Bundler::GemRequireError)
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
  /var/www/geia.junyuzhu.com/public_html/testapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/www/geia.junyuzhu.com/public_html/testapp/config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
  /var/www/geia.junyuzhu.com/public_html/testapp/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

I have tried to install nodejs and restart the apache server. It doesn't help with this issue.

`bundle show uglifier` gives

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.4
```

I assume I have uglifier installed correctly.

Also `gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby` is uncommented in Gemfile.

Please help, I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/428) with therubyracer and Ruby 2.4. There are a couple of additional issues with Ruby 2.4 compatibility which are tracked in their issue tracker at https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/430.

You should use an earlier version of Ruby, e.g. 2.3.3 until a new version is therubyracer is released.

*BTW: There are several gems which are not yet compatible with Ruby 2.4. In order to shield you from experiencing a large amount of compatibility issues after a new release, it is probably wise to not upgrade on first day of release*

Answer (score 0):

In the default rails `Gemfile`, the line for the gem `therubyracer` is commented out. If you uncomment it, you'll get that gem and it should work. (solved the problem for me)

OR

Run Following Commend

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Uglifier is a JS wrapper and it needs a JS runtime running or an JS interpreter